# JUnit 5 says it can run on Java 8 but getting UnsupportedClassVersionError error

Tags: java, junit5

Trying to run JUnit 5.  It's throwing this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/junit/platform/jfr/FlightRecordingListener has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

This is what I'm running.

From the terminal:

```
$java -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

On this page:  https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/, it says:

> 1.2. Supported Java Versions
>
> JUnit 5 requires Java 8 (or higher) at runtime. However, you can still
> test code that has been compiled with previous versions of the JDK.

This is a list of all the JUnit 5 libs I downloaded:

```
Oct  9 10:15 hamcrest-core-2.2.jar
Oct  9 10:09 junit-jupiter-5.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:09 junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:09 junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:09 junit-jupiter-migrationsupport-5.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:09 junit-jupiter-params-5.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:11 junit-platform-commons-1.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:11 junit-platform-console-1.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:10 junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:10 junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:11 junit-platform-jfr-1.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:10 junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:10 junit-platform-reporting-1.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:10 junit-platform-runner-1.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:10 junit-platform-suite-api-1.7.0.jar
Oct  9 10:10 junit-platform-testkit-1.7.0.jar
```

So I'm super confused by the error as org/junit/platform/jfr/FlightRecordingListener has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0)... which is version 11 right?  So how can the Junit 5 documents say 1.8 (52) is supported -- unless I'm doing something wrong that is???

Comment: Downloaded from where? Have you tried using maven or similar build system to manage your dependencies and provide the canonical jars?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `junit-platform-jfr` was [only added with 1.7.0](https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.junit.platform.jfr.FlightRecordingListener), and it may not support older JREs. Is there a particular reason you "downloaded" all those jars, or are you just copying everything regardless of whether you need it?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas... from the link on junit5.org... https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.junit.jupiter%20AND%20v:5.7.0

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yeah, I was just doing the grand-slam of grabbing everything in the repo.  So I took junit-platform-jfr out of the classpath and it works.  Thanks.  Marking your comment as the answer.

Comment: The _real_ answer is to use Maven or Gradle and simply let it pull in the dependencies that are required.

Comment: The documentation still lacks a note that the JUnit Platform JFR module requires Java 11 at runtime and is an experiment. Would you please open an issue athttps://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues -- thanks in advance.